# Incorrect output while making bib file

Tags: bibtex

Here is one of my bib entry

```
@InProceedings{linden,
author = {F. Van Der Linden, J. Bosch, E. Kamsties, K. K{\"a}ns{\"a}l{\"a} and Henk Obbink},
title = {Software Product Family Evaluation},
booktitle = {Software Product-Family Engineering, 5th International Workshop, PFE 2003},
address = {Siena, Italy},
month = {November},
year = {2004},
pages = {352-369}
}
```

and this is the output

```
[F. Van Der Linden and Obbink(2004)] F Van Der Linden EKKK J Bosch, Obbink H (2004)
Software product family evaluation. In: Software Product-Family Engineering, 5th International
Workshop, PFE 2003, Siena, Italy, pp 352{369
```

If you see it has just put EKKK JBosh etc instead of full E. Kamsties etc . Also the special chracters K{\"a} aren't read properly in bibliographies.

I have tried the IEEETran and even Springer latex templates to fix it but in vain.

I am using TexMaker and MikTex2.9 for making these files.

Urgent Help required

Comment: Try this for the `author` field: `author={van der Linden, F. and Bosch, J. and Kamsties, K. and K{\"a}ns{\"a}l{\"a}, K. and Obbink, Henk}`

Answer (score 4):

You've got stray commas and no "and"s in your bibtex

```
author = {F. Van Der Linden, J. Bosch, E. Kamsties, K. K{\"a}ns{\"a}l{\"a} and Henk Obbink},
```

should be

```
author = {Van Der Linden, F. and J. Bosch and E. Kamsties and 
          K. K{\"a}ns{\"a}l{\"a} and Henk Obbink},
```

Comment: If one uses `F. Van Der Linden`, then the given name is `F. Van Der` and the family name is `Linden`; the "comma form" should be used when the family name consists of more than one word, so I fixed your code.

Comment: After these changes I get following error. When I do the second PDFLatex (pdflatex ->bibtex ->pdflatex->pdflatex) I got following error... **! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.40 Software—Practice & Experience 41(8):883--897**...which looks quite confusing as on line 40 is this command \institute

Comment: i guess your .bib file needs \& instead of & for that journal's entry.  note that this is _totally_ unrelated to the previous problem you were getting.